# C# WPF Populating datagrid with list

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, datagrid

I have written this code which loops round re-creating a new list every iteration. The object is to show the refreshed list in the datagrid each iteration (which should occur every 1s or so).

I think i have made a mistake somewhere in the naming or binding in xaml, because my understanding is that the datagrid should automatically populate the returned list but at the moment it is doing nothing and remaining blank - what do i do to make the datagrid populate the list?

The code of the iteration is like this:

```
int i = 0;
do
{
    i += 1;
    UDPDataGrid.ItemsSource = LoadTimestamp(i);
    UDPDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
} while (FinalExit == false);
```

LoadTimestamp passes argument i, and returns a list as summarised in the shortened snippet below:

```
private List<RowEntry> LoadTimestamp(int i)
{
    // Initialise datagroup
    List<RowEntry> TimestampGroup = new List<RowEntry>();

    // Set port receiving
    UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(int.Parse(txtPort.Text));
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    ....................
    ....................
    ....................

    return TimestampGroup;
}
```

Finally, i have the entry in the window.xaml file as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="UDP_Receiver.MainWindow"
..........
Title="UDP Receiver" Height="750" Width="1200">
..........    
<Grid Margin="0,0,16,34">
<DataGrid Name="UDPDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding TimestampGroup}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="29,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1107"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: While the `do-while` loop is running, nothing will work, because it's blocking the application from work (try to drag App's Window for test). Use `Task.Run()` or `Timer`, or `async-await` instead. Where the loop is located? And can you show full `LoadTimestamp` code?

Comment: Note: `ItemsSource="{Binding TimestampGroup}"` and `UDPDataGrid.ItemsSource = LoadTimestamp(i)` are mutual-excluding operations. Select one: `Binding`+`ObservableCollection` form the answer, or `ItemsSource =` with `List`. Or it's better to learn something about `INotifyPropertyChanged` and its implementation. I understand the problem but can't answer the question because it need more details and clarity and more code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ObservableCollection, something like it

```
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            i += 1;
            LoadTimestamp(int i);
        } while (FinalExit == false);


    public ObservableCollecation<RowEntry> TimestampGroup {set; get;} = new ObservableCollecation<RowEntry>();
    
    private void LoadTimestamp(int i)
    {
        TimestampGroup.Clear();

        // Set port receiving
        UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(int.Parse(txtPort.Text));
        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        // Update collection TimestampGroup here
    }
```

Comment: I based my code on this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/datagrid-in-wpf/ which does not use observablecollection?

Comment: And your approach doesn't work. It works only if you initialized your collection once. If you need to change it on air you should use ObservableCollection.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` just provides UI refresh while you add/remove rows without forcing DataGrid to refresh it's layout. Assigning `ItemsSource` is ok instead. But the OP's problem is outside of this. The problem is frozen App because the `do-while` loop is blocking Main UI Thread. Thus, this answer is useful but wouldn't help.